# Symfony2 - DomCrawler - fetch element's content by it's neighbour content in regex

Tags: regex, xml, symfony, web-crawler, domcrawler

I have this xml:

```
<Item id="3" idLevel="3">
    <Label qualifier="Usual">
        <LabelText language="ALL">BE01</LabelText>
    </Label>
    <Label qualifier="Usual">
        <LabelText language="EN">R&#xc9;GION DE BRUXELLES-CAPITALE / BRUSSELS HOOFDSTEDELIJK GEWEST</LabelText>
    </Label>
</Item>
<Item id="4" idLevel="3">
    <Label qualifier="Usual">
        <LabelText language="ALL">BE001</LabelText>
    </Label>
    <Label qualifier="Usual">
        <LabelText language="EN">VLAAMS GEWEST</LabelText>
    </Label>
</Item>
<Item id="123" idLevel="3">
    <Label qualifier="Usual">
        <LabelText language="ALL">RO001</LabelText>
    </Label>
    <Label qualifier="Usual">
        <LabelText language="EN">MACROREGIUNEA DOI</LabelText>
    </Label>
</Item>
```

I would like to fetch a value of a `<LabelText language="EN">` where the neighbour `<LabelText language="ALL">` starts with "BE" and has 3 numbers after.

In this case I would get a value of a second xml element in example: VLAAMS GEWEST

I have an idea how to approach it in uggly way, but I believe there should be more flexible and elegant way to do it:

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addXmlContent($xml);
$crawler = $crawler->filterXPath('//Item[@idLevel="3"]');

foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    // here I check if inside element's neighbour has value of "BE" and three numbers after with regex
}
```

Is there a way to handle it with `DomCrawler` instead of iterating all elements and checking each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a single XPath expression that will get just your required text:

```
//Item[@idLevel="3"]/Label[string-length(preceding-sibling::Label/LabelText/text()) = 5 and starts-with(preceding-sibling::Label/LabelText/text(), "BE") and number(substring(preceding-sibling::Label/LabelText/text(), 3)) = number(substring(preceding-sibling::Label/LabelText/text(), 3))]/LabelText[@language="EN"]/text()
```

Breaking it down:

- `//Item[@idLevel="3"]` - gets the `Item` nodes with `idLevel` attribute with value `3`
- `/Label` - its `Label` children that have...
- `[string-length(preceding-sibling::Label/LabelText/text()) = 5` - a sibling `Label/LabelText` nodes with text length equal to 5...
- `and starts-with(preceding-sibling::Label/LabelText/text(), "BE")` - and having text starting with `BE`
- `and number(substring(preceding-sibling::Label/LabelText/text(), 3)) = number(substring(preceding-sibling::Label/LabelText/text(), 3))]` - and the last 3 chars are digits
- `/LabelText[@language="EN"]/text()` - get the text of the `LabelText` node with a `language` attribute having text `EN`

Comment: Briliant! Thank you for including explanation

Comment: btw, where could I find docs to read about these conditions inside filterXPath? I need to expand it a little bit.

Comment: I think there are tons of resources on this. (Un)?fortunately, I had to learn XPath on an ad-hoc basis. I used to consult http://zvon.org ([here is a Zvon XPath tutorial](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html)). However, there are lots of good stuff here, on SO, too. BTW, how do you need to adjust the expression?